# VBA Group Rows by TRUE/FALSE Condition

Tags: vba

New to VBA. I am trying to group all rows in column A that are FALSE. The code below works for grouping blanks. Is there a SpecialCells function for TRUE/FALSE or should I use another function?

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim falseRange As Range
Dim grp As Range
Set rng = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Set falseRange = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

For Each grp In falseRange
grp.Rows.Group
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim falseRange As Range
    Dim grp As Range

    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1))
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=CStr(False), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            Set falseRange = .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    For Each grp In falseRange.Areas '<--| group contiguous cells toghether
        grp.Rows.Group
    Next

End Sub
```

a refactoring of which could be:

```
Sub main()    
    Dim falseRange As Range
    Dim grp As Range

    Set falseRange = GetFalseRange(Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)))

    If Not falseRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each grp In falseRange.Areas '<--| group contiguous cells toghether
            grp.Rows.Group
        Next
    End If
End Sub


Function GetFalseRange(rng As Range) As Range
    With rng
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=CStr(False), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set GetFalseRange = .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: you are welcome. In a minute 'm posting a little refactoring of my code to have it more "usable".

Comment: The refactoring makes sense to me. Thank you again.